# Data not inserted into an sql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a signup page and a database, the objective is simple:

- create a signup page
- a login page
- and based on the role of user it will redirect the user to it s own page

I have used a template for the signup and login page the data can be inserted and when I click submit it just reload

signup.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'lib/password.php';

require 'config.php';


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SignUp</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load",             
function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ 
window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
 />

 <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
  family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

   <!-- main -->
<div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
<a href="index.html" class="button">Return</a>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<div class="main-agileinfo">
<div class="agileits-top">
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
         <input class="text" type="text"  name="nom" placeholder="nom"     
required="">
           <input class="text" type="text"  name="prenom" 
placeholder="prenom" required="">
                <input class="text" type="text"  name="CIN" 
placeholder="CIN" required="">
                <input class="text email" type="email" name="email" 
placeholder="Email" required="">

                <input class="number" type="text" name="numtel1" 
placeholder="numtel1">
                <input class="number" type="text" name="numtel2" 
placeholder="numtel2">
                <input class="text" type="password"  name="password_1"     
placeholder="Password" required="">
                <input class="text w3lpass" type="password"      
name="password_2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="">
                <input class="Date" type="Date" name="Date" 
placeholder="datedenaissance">
                <input class="Address" type="text" name="Address" 
placeholder="Address">
    <div class="wthree-text">
    <div class="clear"> </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"></button>
        </form>
    <p>Have an Account? <a href="login.php"> Login in</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

config.php

```
<?php

$name = "";
$prenom = "";
$CIN =  "";
$email =  "";
$password =  "";
$numtel1 =  "";
$numtel2 = "";
$Date = "";
$Address =  "";
$errors = array();



$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "stage";
$connection= mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die ("Database connection failed test :" .mysqli_connect_error() .     
mysqli_connect_errno() );
} 

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
$name = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$CIN = $_POST['CIN'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password1 = $_POST['password_1'];
$numtel1 = $_POST['numtel1'];
$numtel2 = $_POST['numtel2'];
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];

$query = "INSERT INTO utilisateur     
(`nom`,`prenom`,`CIN`,`email`,`password`,`numtel1`,`Address`) VALUES 
  ('$name','$prenom','$CIN','$email','$password1','$numtel1','$numtel2','$Address')";

mysqli_query($connection,$query);
}
?>
```

Ps. Database name is "stage"
     the table that i want to insert the data to is "utilisateur"
  the table contains :
`ID_UTILISATEUR` (primary , AI )
`ID_VILLE`(index)
`ID_TYPE_UTILISATEUR`(index)
`ID_ETAT_UTILISATEUR`(index)
`ID_PAYS`(index)
`ID_SEXE`(index)
`NOM`
`PRENOM`
`CIN`
`EMAIL`
`NUMTEL1`
`NUMTEL2`
`ADRESSE`
`DATE_NAISSANCE`

Submitting the form will add data to database

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  If not, are you _checking_ for errors?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: hello @PatrickQ 
my question is " why when i submit the signup form the data in not inserted into the database?
i ve taken care of most errors so when i hit submit it shows no errors
as if it s working perfectly
but when i open the database it s empty

Answer (score 1):

You have given **same page name** in your **form action** that why it is reloading the page. i.e

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
```

It should be like this :

```
<form action="config.php" method="post">
```

Please change it .

Comment: hmmm it doesn t make sense
i know that 
<form action="signup.php" method="post"> 
will reload the page and changing it to 
<form action="config.php" method="post"> will take you to config.php which has the connection settings which is a blank page 
my problem is that it does not insert data to database table